# Mobile Safari removes body background image

Tags: iphone, ios, css, mobile-safari

http://www.samson-book.com

This site has a background image set via CSS on the page body. it displays on every desktop browser, and android, but NOT on mobile safari in iOS. I cannot figure out why.

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
  background-image: url("img/bg_small.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #000;
  }
  #coverbox {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but have u tryede just single line it like:

```
background: url('img/bg_small.jpg') no-repeat top center #000;
```

the top center is just alignment so it wil stick to the top of the device and center it automaticly. Hope it helps normaly works for me.

Comment: can you test this for me? i've added this line to my css

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this, but I suspect its because the iPhone retina screen has a width of 640px, which is greater than the `max-width: 480px` you specified in your CSS.

Comment: That makes total sense. I'm going to fix this, but I do not have an iPhone to test on.